How to manage GPIOs on the Raspberry Pi using the command line? And other clarifications
TLDR; doubts:

When using CLI, what is the easiest way to manage GPIOs on the Pi? What is the more correct (official) way?
Is there some official documentation about this topic for the Pi and Raspberry Pi OS? (I wasn't able to find it)
What are gpiochip512, gpiochip570, gpiochip578 that I see when doing ls /sys/class/gpio/?
Are there other ways other than /sys/class/gpio/export and pinctrl to control GPIOs?
What are the benefits from using one method over the other?


Context
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS (Bookworm). I was using Raspbian until last week when I upgraded to the latest Raspberry Pi OS (I delayed that because I didn't have a real need to upgrade and updating always takes some time).
Well now I see that the method I was using to access gpio pins and using them changed.
Example
The example below just turns on a LED attached to GPIO 13.
Method 1 - /sys/class/gpio/export
I was using:
echo 13 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio13/direction
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio13/value

But that now throws an error:
$ echo 13 > /sys/class/gpio/export
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

So I did some online searching and found these two resources:

An answer to "Trying to write to /sys/class/gpio/export – write error: Invalid argument - Super User"
Accessing GPIO pins from a BASH script on a Raspberry Pi 5 - Raspberry Pi Forums.

The first one states that the GPIO pin numbers have changed somehow and I was able to use this to replaces my previous code to:
echo 525 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio525/direction
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio525/value

To come up with that 525 this was my logic:
$ ls /sys/class/gpio/
export  gpiochip512  gpiochip570  gpiochip578  unexport
$ cat /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip5*/ngpio
58
8
2

So I guessed that the one starting with 512 was the one I could use, it's the only one that has 40 or more pins. And then I just added 13 to that starting point.
Method 2 - pinctrl
I also tried pinctrl from the second link, which translates my example to:
pinctrl set 13 op
pinctrl set 13 dh


you forgot to define the meaning of best way ... otherwise a good question ... upvote ... perhaps ask how to manage ...? instead

As noted this is off topic and would only get opinions. The simple answer is NONE OF THE ABOVE. pinctrl is a kludge for testing and sysfs is obsolete. Do some research. This has been discussed to death on this (and other) sites.

@Milliways Not so helpful comment... I did some looking around but I didn't find a good source to allow me to create my own opinion and I'm not an expert, otherwise I wouldn't be asking things here. You could point in some direction. It's like if I told someone learning a language: "hey bro it's super easy, just look online".

If you edit your question to make it more specific and answerable and ONLY ASK a single question about WHAT YOU ACTUALLY are trying to do are more likely to get answers. See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

hey bro it's super easy, just look online ;-).

@Milliways: The rules do allow "subjective questions", and this one seems reasonable enough.

You asked "How to manage GPIOs on the Raspberry Pi using the command line?"
The discussion in Current proper way to interface GPIO from C code? may be instructive (but not especially helpful) but does have links to some answers.
The simple answer is that the old way of doing things from the Command Line really doesn't work (for reasons which are too complex to explain in a short answer). It IS possible, for limited uses using gpiod tools.
The simplest approach is to use one of the libraries. gpiozero is a python library, well documented with examples and the closest to "official" support.
There are other libraries. Controlling Raspberry Pi GPIO with c and Python is my (slightly dated) assessment.

"discussing the limitations" -> My cursory awareness of said flame wars is that this primarily refers to state being contained by the application (so you can't easily set the ongoing state of a pin from the command line).  However, the document from Rpi Ltd. linked by K. Gibson in comments (dated 8-21-24) says "In order to make the move from the persistent operations of the previous sysfs to libgpiod easier, the Raspberry Pi kernel modifies this behaviour so that the state of a GPIO IS retained when a program that has changed the value (e.g. gpioset, see below) exits."

Based on the number of "close votes" (4 so far!) your Q is apparently perceived as "soliciting opinion". However, the rules here allow for "subjective questions". I'll offer the following answer.
That said, your question: "What is the more correct (official) way?" seems a bit odd to me. Why would you worry about the "official" way? As a partial answer, I'd suggest you worry less about the "official" way, and concentrate on what works, and makes sense to you. You'll ultimately get the answers to these important questions from experience, and that will ultimately come from use - your use... not someone else's, and especially not from pushy know-it-alls masquerading as software developers.
As far as "official documentation", you'll find a white paper titled "A history of GPIO usage on Raspberry Pi devices, and current
best practices" prepared by "The Raspberries" on their Product Information Portal. It strikes me as a brief and objective attempt to review the current state of GPIO control for Raspberry Pi; I'd recommend that you read it.
AFAIK, using sysfs to control GPIO pins in a discrete, "ON or OFF" manner, is a non-starter - it is no longer supported by the kernel. However, sysfs is very much alive and well for GPIO control; for example in PWM applications, or using I2C for things like sensor interface. Honestly - I can no longer recall why the Linux kernel crowd pushed "discrete" GPIO control out of sysfs - but it may have been $$$.
There are several different solutions for "discrete" GPIO control that I am aware of - and certainly more that I have no experience with - I'll list the ones I have some personal experience with:

pinctrl - which you've mentioned
wiringPi - a "born again" GPIO library & "tool set" making a comeback :)
libgpiod (and libgpiod tools) - the "kernel-sponsored" library

Personally, I've found pinctrl to be the most straightforward & easiest to use. I've only begun using it recently - having used wiringPi for several years before the package was dropped in bookworm. I've tried libgpiod, but found it... well you can read my thoughts here in a question I asked recently that's not too different from yours.
